# How can i get the post content without html tags?

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress

I am using [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/) and wants to parse post content (clear text) without html tags.

I tried using `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($posts))` and `strip_tags($posts);` but not able to remove html tags from the JSON.

Not sure if i am placing it properly as i am new to php.

```
public function get_category_posts() {
global $json_api;
$category = $json_api->introspector->get_current_category();
if (!$category) {
  $json_api->error("Not found.");
}
$posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array(
  'cat' => $category->id
));
$result = strip_tags($posts);
return $this->posts_object_result($result, $category);
}
```

**JSON**:

```
"posts": [
{
  "id": 3454,
  "type": "post",
  "status": "publish",
  "title": "XYZ JOINS",
  "content": "<p>This is the content that should not have html tags.<\/p>\n",
  "date": "2012-05-16 22:06:55"
}
]
```

I want to remove `<p></p>` html tags from above json. There many div and other html tags in the content.

Comment: Can you give some sample input/output with what is wrong and how you'd prefer it to look, since it's a little difficult to tell what you want at the moment

Comment: Thanks! I modify the question for more clarification.

Comment: `strip_tags` only work for strings.. maybe you should use this function just for `Content` and not the entire Posts?

Comment: @Philipp can you give example on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is a simple regex to strip html style tags from the content. Maybe this would work

```
str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')
```

Comment: Do i need to loop on all $posts, not sure how to do that on php

Comment: depends on your php code implementation. if you are fetching data again and again then yes

Comment: what is gi in str.replace?

Comment: its the specification setting for type of replacing the string